# PhoneGap / Cordova 2.4 BarcodeScanner Plugin on Android no results

Tags: android, cordova, barcode-scanner

I have gotten the BarcodeScanner working in PhoneGap 2.4 - Android.

It scans the qrcode fine, but there is no response handed back to the callback in the JavaScript.

I get the following in Eclipse logs:

```
08-06 00:50:13.910: D/dalvikvm(14608): GC_CONCURRENT freed 21K, 16% free 6889K/8199K, paused 12ms+13ms, total 59ms
08-06 00:50:13.980: D/dalvikvm(14608): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 533K, 22% free 6458K/8199K, paused 25ms, total 25ms
08-06 00:50:14.030: D/dalvikvm(14608): GC_CONCURRENT freed 34K, 16% free 6889K/8199K, paused 12ms+4ms, total 50ms
08-06 00:50:14.030: D/dalvikvm(14608): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 13ms
08-06 00:50:14.050: D/DecodeHandler(14608): Found barcode in 55 ms
08-06 00:50:14.070: D/dalvikvm(14608): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 92K, 13% free 7175K/8199K, paused 22ms, total 22ms
08-06 00:50:14.090: D/CaptureActivityHandler(14608): Got decode succeeded message
08-06 00:50:16.060: D/CaptureActivityHandler(14608): Got return scan result message
08-06 00:50:16.180: D/DroidGap(14608): Incoming Result
08-06 00:50:16.180: D/DroidGap(14608): Request code = 195543262
08-06 00:50:16.180: D/DroidGap(14608): We have a callback to send this result to
08-06 00:50:16.180: D/DroidGap(14608): Resuming the App
```

And I'm using default JS to trigger the scan, for testing purposes:

```
var scanCode = function() {
    window.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
        function(result) {
        alert("Scanned Code: " + result.text 
                + ". Format: " + result.format
                + ". Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
    }, function(error) {
        alert("Scan failed: " + error);
    });
}
```

I was wondering if any of you have heard of this issue before or know where to start looking for the possible causes?

Does it have something to do with the pausing and resuming of the app?

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Im facing the same God damn issue. did you solved this issue? Please paste as your answer . thanks

Comment: Sorry - no I have not spent more time on this, yet.  I plan on abandoning this and upgrading "other" plugins to work with more current versions of phonegap.

Here's my iOS example:
https://github.com/zeroasterisk/PhoneGap-BarcodeScanner-Example-iOS

When I have an Android one, I'll interlink.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna build Barcode Scanner try this tutorial form [SAP](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-56113). It works with cordova CLI. i have tried it and it works well.